# Onlick button always posts value of html button

Tags: php, html

I used the following code to post a search value via an html button. But `onlick` seem to be not working. The value is posted whether I click the button or not. How can fix this problem??

```
<form method="post" action="urban.php" id="search_form">
        <input type="button" class="button" name="search" value="Urban" onlick="<?php $_POST['search'] = 'Urban'; ?>">
</form>

    <?php if(isset($_POST['search']) && !empty($_POST['search']))
        {
            include('searchfunction.php');

            if(count($data) > 0)
            {
    ?>
                        <script type="text/javascript"> 
                        $(document).ready(function(){

                        var description = ''; 
                        var myPlaylist = [ 
    <?php
                            echo(implode(',', $data));
    ?>
                 ]; 

                        $('#main').ttwMusicPlayer(myPlaylist, { 
                        autoPlay:false, 
                        description:description, }
                        );

                        }); 
                        </script>
    <?php
            }
            else
            {
                echo ('No sounds found.');
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: with onclick you call a javascript function. something like onclick="doSearch()". pretty weird what you are doing there, i don't understand it really

Comment: `onlick="<?php $_POST['search'] = 'Urban'; ?>"` - What is this code even _supposed_ to do?

Comment: It simply post the button value. I have different categories and I want to let the results appear when the button or the category is pressed.

Comment: @PhilippBraun: I don't think it does what you think it does.  When the page loads, the first PHP to get executed is to overwrite whatever's in `$_POST['search']` with the value `'Urban'`.  Which is odd because the form value for `search` will _always_ be `'Urban'` because it's coded into the `button` as such.  And what ends up in the emitted `onclick=""`?  An empty string?  `true`?  An assignment statement doesn't really produce a string, does it?  And how is "the value posted" without clicking the button?  It really sounds like you need some basic PHP/JavaScript/HTML tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP & JS are not executed at the same time : PHP is executed server side, to create the HTML code. Javascript is executed on the client side, when all HTML is already rendered.

Here is a quick fix:

```
<form method="post" action="urban.php" id="search_form">
        <input type="hidden" name="search" value="<?php echo 'Urban';?>"
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<?php if(isset($_POST['search']) && !empty($_POST['search']))
    {
        include('searchfunction.php');

        if(count($data) > 0)
        {
?>
                    <script type="text/javascript"> 
                    $(document).ready(function(){

                    var description = ''; 
                    var myPlaylist = [ 
<?php
                        echo(implode(',', $data));
?>
             ]; 

                    $('#main').ttwMusicPlayer(myPlaylist, { 
                    autoPlay:false, 
                    description:description, }
                    );

                    }); 
                    </script>
<?php
        }
        else
        {
            echo ('No sounds found.');
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it didn't actually solve my problem but brought me closer to a solution. At the end I used instead of a button simply a submit button. `<input type="submit" name="search" value="Transport" class="button" />`

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing PHP and HTML, but that's not going to work like you want. PHP code is interpreted on the server while html is "executed" in the users browser. You can submit the form and give the values to the server.

Use a submit button

```
<input type="submit">
```

or add the right onclick function

```
    <input type="button" class="button" name="search" value="Urban" onlick="this.parentNode.submit();">
```